# Mac OS Big Sur redis.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture MAMP

Tags: mamp, macos-big-sur, phpredis

I have installed redis on my mac Big Sur 11.0.1 and also, I have installed MAMP. Now, I am trying to add phpredis as redis extension but I am having php error while loading redis.so file which I created using cloned github phpredis used phpize `./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/php-config`, then restarted the MAMP, it throws the following error

```
[09-Jan-2021 23:47:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' (tried: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/redis.so (dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/redis.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/redis.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/redis.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture), /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/redis.so.so (dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/redis.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Since new Macbook has arm architecture which is different than the previous architecture and MAMP expects to have `Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64 redis.so` file. While generating redis.so file on arm architecture the redis.so file has `Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64` property which is incompatible for MAMP. That's why, it was throwing the above error. 
The solution for me was - generating redis.so file on Mac i386 architecture with the same phpize version.

Comment: Can you show me how to generate the redis.so on Mac i386?

Comment: @Muh Ghazali Akbar, For that, Luckily, I had older mac where I downloaded the php-redis and then, I phpize on the folder which created a redis.so file then, I air-dropped it to the M1 macbook. After that, I added to the folder where extensions are being loaded. This how I am running the redis.so extension at the moment.